# How to run React App created by create-react-app in Salesforce

Tags: reactjs, salesforce, create-react-app, salesforce-lightning

I want to run a React app inside salesforce Lightning container. I built the app with npm run build, upload zip file but nothing works. All I can get is a blank page.

Build folder before zip

[image]

Zip and uploaded to Static resource

[image]

In deveoper console

```
<aura:application >
    <lightning:container src="{!$Resource.Mirage + '/index.html'}"/>
</aura:application>
```

The preview page is blank and I don't know how to do it properly. I feel like it cannot load my resource.

Do I have to give up on CRA and build custom webpack?

Comment: FYI, this will work fine as a VF page... There's probably a way to get it to work in lightning container, but there are definitely more challenges and few benefits. Typically if you are using react in salesforce, it should be as a stand alone SPA anyway (which VF is perfect for)

Comment: @NSjonas I manage to use as a VF page but it does not work well. New problem can be found here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63247793/how-to-use-visualforce-page-with-lightningcontainer-react-in-lightning-app-buil

Answer (score 0):

Full disclosure: I never tried this. But it [looks like](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=pages_static_resources.htm&type=5) you have to:

> To reference a file in an archive, use the URLFOR function.

I am not 100% sure this is the answer.

Let me know.

Comment: I figure out my code in console is right but the zip is wrong. I should only zip the contents not the parent folder. Now I encounter another problem XD

Comment: What new problem?

Comment: I import that aura:application in visualforce page, it's fine when preview. but when add it to application. there is an error: `Refused to frame 'https://mirage-video-dev-ed--ltng.container.lightning.com/' because an ancestor violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "frame-ancestors https://mirage-video-dev-ed--c.visualforce.com".`