# How to use visualforce page with lightning:container React in Lightning app builder?

Tags: reactjs, salesforce, visualforce, salesforce-lightning

I try to create a React app inside visualforce page via lightning. When I click preview in visualforce setting, everything is fine.

[image]

But when I use it in Lightning app builder it does not work. It shows
[image]

The error: `Refused to frame 'https://mirage-video-dev-ed--ltng.container.lightning.com/' because an ancestor violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "frame-ancestors https://mirage-video-dev-ed--c.visualforce.com".`
Also really weird that if I right click and choose "Reload frame", it works.

[image]

Visualforce code

```
<apex:page >
    <apex:includeLightning />
    <div id="hello" />
    <script>
        $Lightning.use("c:myFirstApp", function() {
            $Lightning.createComponent("lightning:container",
              { src: "{!$Resource.hello + '/index.html'}"},
              "hello",
              function(cmp) {
                console.log("created");
                // do some stuff
              }
          );

        });
    </script>
</apex:page>
```

myFirstApp

```
<aura:application access="global" extends="ltng:outApp">
    <aura:dependency resource="lightning:container"/>
</aura:application>
```

Is there a way to fix it? I cannot find the way to load aura:application directly so if there is a way please show me.

Comment: FYI, please use salesforce.stackexchange in the future for questions related directly to SF

Answer (score 0):

You've got a bit of a inception problem going on... You just need to mount your react app directly inside of the VF page.  No need to use a `lightning:container`.

See my [B.A.S.S.](https://github.com/ChuckJonas/bad-ass-salesforce-stack) project. This is proven to work and be extremely scalable.

Example VF Page with react app:

```html
<apex:page showHeader="true" sidebar="false" standardStylesheets="false" docType="html-5.0">
    <script type="text/javascript">
        //rest details
        const __ACCESSTOKEN__ = '{!$Api.Session_ID}';
        const __RESTHOST__ = '';
    </script>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <!-- Your react entry point -->
    <script type='text/javascript' src="{!URLFOR($Resource.app, 'dist/app.js')}"></script>
</apex:page>
```

It is also possible to to run a [React App directly inside a LWC](https://github.com/ChuckJonas/lwc-react-webpack-demo), although no recommended.